# Ajax not finding url

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, url

Quick question I have been working at but can't seem to get it fixed.

I have a ajax call but it is not getting a response from the php file, it seems to be loading a 404 instead.

The url in the address bar is "mydomain.com/checkcity/"

The location of the file with the ajax is "/php/advert/script.php"

The location of the php file to be called is "/php/advert/available.php"

I am using virtual urls through the use of htaccess.

Here is my ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/available.php",
        data: "city="+city,
        success: function(response){
        alert(response);
}
});
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

One thing I noticed is when I search the url in the address bar it will load the php file just not with the ajax call.

I am running this currently on Apache 2.2 localhost

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but shouldn't the url be `url: "available.php",` without the `/`? (Or with the complete path) Now it just points to the root.

Comment: Was your available.php a real file or do you emulate it in the index.php? In ajax you give a parameter `city`. Did you also specify a `city=xx` when calling it as a test via the address-bar? Perhaps you do something in your index that if specified (via ajax or url) you give a 404 and if not specified you return an other page.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're seeing the `404` error message in the error log/console for your browser? It should also be displaying the `URL` that is returning the `404` response which, given your request, would be: `http://www.mysite.com/available.php`.

### Problem

The problem is that your ajax call contains a `/` at the start of the `URL` parameter. This signifies the root domain of the website (i.e. it points to `http://www.mysite.com/available.php`).

```
url: "/available.php",
```

### Solution

Simply change the url parameter to one of the following *correct* `URL`s

```
url: "http://www.mysite.com/php/advert/available.php",
```

OR

```
url: "/php/advert/available.php",
```

OR

```
url: "available.php",
```

OR

```
url: "./available.php",
```

---

#### Code for clarification

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/advert/available.php",
    data: "city="+city,
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thats what I tried with those urls, in firebug I see that it is not found.

Comment: I have a setting in php index.php where if the url is not found in the database it will redirect to 404 page... So perhaps this could be why it is not finding the url... but as I said when I type the url in the browser it will load.

Comment: So you have tried them? `index.php` has nothing to do with it (unless the file doesn't exist; but you say you **can** get it through the browser directly).. Okay, I'm assuming that the `URL` you type into the browser is `http://www.mysite.com/php/advert/available.php`? Type it into the browser (to make sure it works) and then copy/paste (to avoid errors/typos) the complete url (http:// - included) as in the edit above.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then could you please tell me _exactly_ what the `URL` in the console is that says `404`? (Feel free to change the site name if you want to.. or alternatively, if at all possible, point me to it?)

Comment: I typed the exact url in ajax and what happens is in firebug it says url not found and it was searching for proper url - http://www.mydomain.com/php/advert/available.php but says its not found when ran in ajax. The site isn't live which is too bad. If I put url "/available.php" or "/anythinghere.php" in the ajax it will go to success and post the alert. But instead of getting a response from the php file it gets info from my 404 page - I am wondering if it is getting sent to a url like mydomain.com/checkcity/available.php then because this doesn't exist it gets sent to a not found page.

Comment: Okay, so can you tell me the actual `url` that you're using? (e.g. `/localhost/mysite/php/advert/available.php`). In firebug it should show `http://localhost/test/fifdle   404 Not Found   2ms` or similar. If those two `URL`s are the same then it **is not** being sent to the wrong `URL`... You said you're running apache; I assume then you're on Linux? What's in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Ok so I have checked and seen that no matter what I put in URL the actual url lookup from is adding what is in the address bar plus what it has in the url parameter. So say I have "available.php" as url and the webpage is "mysite.com/checkcity/" it look for the php file at "mysite.com/checkcity/available.php"... So is there a way to just lookup the url in the ajax call without adding the current URL in the address bar as well. Thanks so much for any help... If not then im just going to make a call in the index file so when that address is lookedup it sends to the file loction.

Comment: I have added some example code to the answer, that `URL` will default back to the root and work it's way up so even if I'm viewing http://mysite.com/level1/level2/thisPage.php it will direct to http://mysite.com/php/advert/available.php. Sorry if you've tried that a 100 times already but please make it 101 - just to be sure. If it still doesn't work, perhaps we can continue this in chat?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I know this is outdated but I thought I would answer why this was happening. I moved on to other things and this was the last thing to do so I was forced to figure it out which actually only took about half hour.

Ajax wasn't reaching the url in chrome but would in firefox. I then found out that "adblock" was blocking the url - This was because the url had "advert" in it and as soon as I relocated and renamed the file, presto *it worked*.

So just in case someone finds themselves in a similar situation.

Thanks