# ajax can't find url of a folder/directory (404)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have some ajax that returns a 404 when trying to find a folder full of images that definitely exists. I tried using the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072396/ajax-not-finding-url) but nothing worked.

```
  var folder = "img/macro";
  $.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
      // add images to html
    }
  });
```

It makes no sense because everything works perfectly locally, but when I push it up to GitHub Pages the console says that `https://example.com/img/macro/` doesn't exist when you try to run that ajax. Yet I can easily just navigate to that location in the address bar with an image filename appended: `https://www.example.com/img/macro/image.jpg`

How do I get the ajax to find this folder of images? Is this a .htaccess problem?

The reason I'm doing this is because I have about 50 images in the folder of `img/macro` that are being procedurally appended into the html so that I don't have to create 50 html elements with unique file names. This way I can just dump all my images into one folder and just have ajax grab them all.

Comment: *" Is this a .htaccess problem"*...basically yes. Directories are typically protected from being indexed in public for obvious security reasons. You may not be protecting it locally.

Comment: @OMiShah would you be useful and direct me to them?

Comment: Since you are locating the file locally you need to know what folder this script above is located in and then plot a course to the correct file.  ../ means to go back a folder, try it!